# Get displays system names from d3shot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, screen-capture

I'm making a program to catch an image from one display and analyze it. I'm using `d3dshot`. I want to show the beginning names of connected displays.

```
import d3dshot
import time

d = d3dshot.create()
d.display = d.displays[2]
for i, x in enumerate(d.displays):
    print(i, ". ",x)
```

The problem is that I get only this:

`0 .  <Display name=Generic PnP Monitor adapter=NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB resolution=1920x1080 rotation=0 scale_factor=1.0 primary=True> 1 .  <Display name=Generic PnP Monitor adapter=NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB resolution=1824x1026 rotation=0 scale_factor=1.0 primary=False> 2 .  <Display name=Generic PnP Monitor adapter=NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB resolution=1920x1080 rotation=0 scale_factor=1.0 primary=False>`

Is there a way to get system names of monitors?

[image: names of monitors in nvidia control panel]

I was trying to use `screeninfo` but the results also weren't useful:

`Monitor(x=1920, y=0, width=1824, height=1026, width_mm=820, height_mm=460, name='\\\\.\\DISPLAY1', is_primary=False) Monitor(x=-1920, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=531, height_mm=299, name='\\\\.\\DISPLAY2', is_primary=False) Monitor(x=0, y=0, width=1920, height=1080, width_mm=521, height_mm=293, name='\\\\.\\DISPLAY3', is_primary=True)`